# Loading text while waiting for a Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to Javascript/Jquery/Ajax and don't know how to get some text to display 'Loading...' while waiting for an ajax call.

So far I have this code which works fin

```
$.get("sum.php", { userid: "<?php echo $userID; ?>"},
           function(data){


                eval(data);

});
```

I want 'Loading...' to appear in a div called Loading until the data is returned from the Ajax call.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

If your loading `div` has ID "loading", you could do something like this...

```
<div id="loading"><img src="spinner.gif" /> Loading...</div>
```

JavaScript using jQuery [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/):

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
   $(this).show();
})
.ajaxStop(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```